# Verbose p4 sync

Tags: version-control, perforce

In the visual Perforce client (p4v) there is an option:

*Show p4 command output for file operations*

When it is enabled, in the log pane I can see detailed logging like this:

```
p4 sync /Users/az/ftp/...#head
//depot/ftp/inc/PICHNL.H  updated  /Users/az/ftp/inc/PICHNL.H
//depot/ftp/src/ftpprot.cpp  updated  /Users/az/ftp/src/ftpprot.cpp
2 files updated
```

Is there something similar in the command line perforce client?

In command line (Cygwin ran in Hudson CI) executing:

```
p4 sync /Users/az/ftp/...#head
```

shows nothing until whole sync is done.

**I would like to have verbose logging when doing `p4 sync`.**

Comment: The output in `p4v` when syncing and in `p4 sync` is exactly the same for me. What's your exact command-line for `p4 sync`?

Comment: p4 sync will show very little if everything's up to date.  Is that why you're not seeing anything?

Comment: I updated my question with exemplary outputs.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, there is no *more* verbose logging available for running commands in CLI. When you perform a `p4 sync //...` it is reporting all the information that it can. In fact the only difference between the performing a sync in P4V and via CLI is that P4V tells you how many files it has updated.

The *Show p4 command output for file operations* option in P4V

> displays all commands issued by P4V,
>   including commands issued by P4V to
>   obtain status information from the
>   Perforce server. [Source: P4V Help file](http://filehost.perforce.com/perforce/r09.2/doc/help/p4v-html-pure/en/Configuring_display_preferences.html)

Comment: Note: more recent versions of P4V now have preferences on how much it displays in the log window.